# Hibernate, java.lang.IllegalStateException ao tentar createQuery [resolved]

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD, but when I try to get the data from the database it's giving me the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@3304e14b is closed
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.errorIfClosed(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:37)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:135)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:116)
    org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:294)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:145)
    ef.uniceplac.users.dao.ProdutosDAO.getTodosProdutos(ProdutosDAO.java:146)
    ef.uniceplac.users.controller.ProdutoServlet.listaProdutos(ProdutoServlet.java:94)
    ef.uniceplac.users.controller.ProdutoServlet.doGet(ProdutoServlet.java:69)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I'm using:

- Eclipse
- Hibernate
- Maven

I'm managing to enter data, the problem is when I try to get them. It executes the command but falls into the exception

My class dao:

```
    public List <Produtos> getTodosProdutos(){
        
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List <Produtos> listaDeProdutos = null;
        
        try(Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()){
            //começa transação
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            
            //busca todos os produtos
            listaDeProdutos = session.createQuery("from Produtos ").getResultList();
            
            //commita transação
            transaction.commit();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            if(transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaDeProdutos;
    }
```

my hibernate.cfg.x:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
           "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
           "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
   
 <hibernate-configuration>  
     <session-factory>  
         <!-- Database connection settings -->
         <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/formiguei</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.username">rubensdimasjr</property>  
         <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>  
   
        
         <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
         <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>  
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
   
         <!-- Mapping files -->  
         <mapping class="ef.uniceplac.users.dao.ProdutosDAO"/>
         <mapping class="ef.uniceplac.users.model.Produtos"/>
      
     </session-factory>  
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

part of servlet:

```
private void listaProdutos(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException{
        List <Produtos> listaProdutos = produtosDao.getTodosProdutos();
        request.setAttribute("listaProdutos", listaProdutos);
        
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

and my jsp:

```
            <c:forEach var="produto" items="${listaProdutos}">
              <div class="row border-bottom">
                <div class="col-1 my-4">
                  <div class="figura">
                    <img src="<c:out value="${produto.linkImagem}" />" alt="<c:out value="${produto.titulo}" />
                      class="rounded">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5 my-4 d-flex flex-column">
                  <span class="fw-bolder fs-5 m-1"><c:out value="${produto.titulo}" /></span>
                  <span class="text-muted fs-6 m-1 text-truncate">${produto.descricao}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 my-4 mx-2 position-relative">
                  <div class="col p-2 rounded-pill bg-secondary text-center position-absolute bottom-0 start-0">
                    <span class="text-white fs-6 fw-bolder">R$ <c:out value="${produto.preco}" />,00</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 my-4 mx-2 position-relative">
                  <div class="col p-2 rounded-pill bg-dark text-center position-absolute bottom-0 start-0">
                    <span class="text-white fw-bolder">ID: <c:out value="${produto.id}" /></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 my-4 position-relative">
                  <div class="mt-5 icons position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">
                  <a href="edita-produto?id=<c:out value="${produto.id}" />">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit fs-6"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="deleta-produto?id=<c:out value="${produto.id}" />">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fs-6 text-danger"></i>
                  </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </c:forEach>
```

Comment: This happens in the catch block when trying to rollback apparently, but the initial exception is not shown because the rollback fails. So try to see what's the initial exception

Comment: Genius!! I checked the exception and didn't make the default constructor in my class, there were two with super();